# Can Heroku websites read Server Side Includes

Tags: heroku, ssi, shtml

I am simply trying to reuse variables across multiple webpages on a heroku app. However, I keep getting that the variable is not found when trying to deploy.

I have saved as html file as shtml. I have also included this line without a script tag  inside index.shtml.

Do heroku apps read server side includes?

Comment: Heroku doesn't provide a web server at all. You need to provide your own, and the right way to do that depends on what you're deploying. Is this just a static site, or is there some back-end technology involved? What buildpack are you using (check with `heroku buildpacks`)?

Comment: Ok, I see that I had a misunderstanding. I am using the heroku/nodejs buildpack. There is some back-end technology for the site as well. So then I need to use something like nginx, apache, or node express and turn SSI on there. Is that correct?

Comment: Express is a common server to use with Node on Heroku, yes. If you can do what you want with that that's what I recommend.